# Importing cython file in python, using pyximport results in the ImportError: because of distutils.error.CompilerError

Tags: python, mingw, cython, importerror, distutils

I have forked scikit-learn github code from https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn. I want to debug this file: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/_mean_shift.py .

I have added

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
bandwidth=0.5
num_mean_shift_iterations=5
num_points=100
centers = [[-1, -1], [-1, 1], [1, -1], [1, 1]]
x1, y = make_blobs(n_samples=num_points, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.4, random_state=42)
clustering = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth, n_jobs = -1, max_iter=num_mean_shift_iterations).fit(x1)
```

in _mean_shift.py. And I am running it using a Sypder environment with Python 3.7 installed on it.

Following is the complete error.

```
ImportError: Building module utils.murmurhash failed ["distutils.errors.CompileError:command 'C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\\\2019\\\\Community\\\\VC\\\\Tools\\\\MSVC\\\\14.24.28314\\\\bin\\\\HostX86\\\\x64\\\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2\n"]
```

where utils.murmurhash is what I am trying to import in python file located at different location.

I have created a new environment in python using: https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html i.e. all the libraries listed on this webpage are installed.

distutils.cfg that contains the following code is located at:
C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\stan_env\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32

[build_ext]
compiler = mingw32
```

I have used:

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
```

in python file before importing cython_files.

Please point me out to the error. Thanks.

Comment: This question lacks a [mcve] and without it is impossible to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: @ead I have added the steps to minimal reproducible example. Please look into the issue. Thanks.

Comment: 1) There must be more information concerning the error printed to stderr 2) It is still unclear which files are you trying to cythonize/compile. 3) Why are you recompiling murmurhash?

Comment: I am just running the file: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/_mean_shift.py with the above-mentioned changes. A function used in this file is implemented in murmurhash. 

murmurhash is the cython file which is getting cythonized with the functional call.

Comment: How can I avoid recompiling if the file is imported in the python file that I am trying to use?

Answer (score 2):

As I see you you are using:

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
```

to compile Cython in order to import *.pyx files.

On the [site](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html#pyximport-cython-compilation-for-developers) it is written:
"If your module **doesn’t** require any extra C libraries or a special build setup, then you can use the pyximport module"

Probably it can cause a problem, because sklearn imports many C libraries.

In order to import *.pyx first you have to compile it by running:

```
# change directory to forked project ([example-how-to-do-that][2])
# only for Windows users with anaconda:
conda activate {environment_name} # the same name which you provided during environment creation
# only for linux users who don't use anaconda:
# source {environment_name}/bin/activate
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

in terminal.

I also had problems when I tried to compile Cython modules directly in the code (by pyximport package). I cannot import them. In my case it was also files from sklearn. And the method with compiling Cython by terminal helped me.